# Have a spinner display right away after refreshing a page on my (Mud)Blazor Server application

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I'm working on a Mudblazor server application and I have it successfully displaying a loading spinner upon the application loading with the code below that exists in `MainLayout.razor`

```
<MudMainContent>
        <MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.ExtraExtraLarge">
            @if (_departments.GetDepartments().DepartmentList is null || _jobs.GetJobs().JobList is null || _departments.GetDepartments().DepartmentList.Count() == 0 || _jobs.GetJobs().JobList.Count() == 0)
            {
                <MudOverlay Visible="true" DarkBackground="true" ZIndex="9999">
                    <MudProgressCircular Color="Color.Secondary" Indeterminate="true" />
                </MudOverlay>
            }
            else
            {
                @Body
            }           
        </MudContainer>
</MudMainContent>
```

The only issue is when I reload the page. The app doesn't display the spinner until about ~3ish seconds later. How do I get it so that the spinner displays instantly upon the user refreshing the page?

I want a loading spinner to display right away upon a user reloading the webpage. What happens instead is that the user clicks reload and the page just stays the same until about ~3ish seconds later in which it displays the spinner.

Comment: What does GetDepartments() do and why isn't it async ?

Answer (score 1):

> [@RBee has a great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76909640/1690217), but I want to provide more context

In general with any UX design where you want something immediate like a *busy* or *progress indicator* at the start of a page load then the most efficient UX pattern is to set the default state of the screen and that indicator so that it is enabled and the indicator is visible.

In all cases, to load data or check other properties in the page load cycle before toggling the indicators will take time, sometimes a really small time, other times much longer. In Blazor Server this is even more relevant than other JS frameworks because the client needs to connect to the server for the logic to be executed. This is the pause or delay that you experience at the start, so given that you want to show the indicator specifically during this time where there is a delay for everything in the view port, then it makes sense that the default state should be for the indicator to be visible.

In Blazor, we have a tendency when we are starting out to *cheat* and execute large complex expressions and or functions in-line with the razor template. ***STOP**!* just because you *can*, doesn't mean you *should*. I encourage all Blazor devs to try to implement a *View Model* pattern for managing visual states, create a discrete valued *property* on the view model or *property*/*field* in the code behind class and databind the any visibility or conditional statements to that property as [@RBee has a demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76909640/1690217).

The problem with the following `@if` block is that there is no way to determine a *default* state, the code **MUST** be executed to determine if the *truthy* or *falsey* branch of the nested razor template should be executed.

```
@if (_departments.GetDepartments().DepartmentList is null 
    || _jobs.GetJobs().JobList is null 
    || _departments.GetDepartments().DepartmentList.Count() == 0 
    || _jobs.GetJobs().JobList.Count() == 0)
```

To make matters worse, `GetDepartments()`, `GetJobs()` functions are executed multiple times in the same expression, these functions are likely to take time to execute and if a cache or *[memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)* mechanism is not in place, those calls could be significant round trips to the server and potentially the database.

Blazor will not store the result of function calls that are used in conditional logic, so if you have multiple in-line code blocks or expressions that have similar logic on the same page, then even if the expression is the same, the expression will need to be evaluated for each instance.

When you convert this to use a single field/property reference, then some optimizations can cache the result for that reference for a given render cycle. But it is still important that the property implementation does not do the work. If you moved the entire expression to a property implementation then we are not much better off, instead we need to move the evaluation to a point in the code where it is evaluated a minimal number of times.

For evaluating conditions of visual assets that you want a *default* state to render first, the first logical event to use is to override the [OnAfterRenderAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0#after-component-render-onafterrenderasync) method. That is rendered *after* the DOM has been evaluated once, so you can see that if our DOM requires code to be evaluated first, then our standard initialization logic hasn't even been executed yet.

Where this can be confusing is in the example for how to [Handle incomplete async actions at render](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0#handle-incomplete-async-actions-at-render)

```
<h1>Sci-Fi Movie Ratings</h1>

@if (movies == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var movie in movies)
        {
            <li>@movie.Title &mdash; @movie.Rating</li>
        }
    </ul>
}

@code {
    private Movies[]? movies;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        movies = await GetMovieRatings(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

`movies` in this case is a good example of using a backing field in Blazor, it looks like it is just executing any arbitrary code in the expression, but it is not, there is nothing arbitrary about that expression. It also uses the same field to render the data as it does to determine the visible state. It is not necessary to create a separate field to track *if movies is available* because the nullability of the field will tell us that.

```
@if (movies == null)
```

is very different to something like:

```
@if (GetMovieRatings(DateTime.Now) == null)
```

even though both might be permissible. Any code you put in-line with the razor template (outside of the `@code` script block) must be evaluated to complete the DOM build and especially the first render, which will occur before the `OnAfterRender` or `OnInitialized` methods and their async variants. The field `movies` in this case is available immediately when the DOM is created.

Comment: Wow, that was a really informative read. Thanks for the deeper dive into @RBee 's response, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: Getting this right is the difference between making Blazor work for you or having to work really hard but still getting a low performing outcome. This comes up a lot in my mentor sessions so now hopefully this can help everyone get into Blazor the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try loading/initializing your Data in the components `OnAfterRender`/`OnAfterRenderAsync` method. While you toggle a `bool` property to keep track of your conditions.

```
<MudMainContent>
        <MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.ExtraExtraLarge">
            @if (loadingData)
            {
                <MudOverlay Visible="true" DarkBackground="true" ZIndex="9999">
                    <MudProgressCircular Color="Color.Secondary" Indeterminate="true" />
                </MudOverlay>
            }
            else
            {
                @Body
            }           
        </MudContainer>
</MudMainContent>

@code{
    bool loadingData = true;
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if(firstRender)
        {
            await GetDepartments();
            await GetJobs();
            loadingData = false;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

[MudBlazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/muwxuilzioSjRRtp)

Comment: This appeared to have worked. Thank you so much!